# d3js chart with crosshair as tooltip: How to Add 2 lines which intersect at cursor position

Tags: javascript, css, charts, d3.js

This example from Mike Bostock shows a tooltip that I am trying to replicate (circle + text element: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569 ).

However, the twist here is that I would like to get rid of the circle, and replace it with cross-hairs, keeping the functionality the same.  My partially functional code is here (line 164 and beyond pasted below: http://tributary.io/inlet/8075741 ).

Despite adding a second line element the vertical line will not render, whereas the horizontal line works as intended.

```
// add cross hairs and floating value on axis
var focus = chart.append("g")
    .attr("class","focus")
    .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("text").attr({"x": 9, "dy": "0.35em"});

    // horizontal crosshair 
    focus.append("line")
          .attr({
            "x1": 0,
            "y1": 0,
            "x2": -width + margin.left,
            "y2": 0
          });



    /* failed attempt to dynamically add vertical line

    focus.append("line")
            .attr({
              "x1": d3.mouse(this)[0],
              "y1": -height + margin.top*4,
              "x2": d3.mouse(this)[0],
              "y2": height
            });
    */

    // failed attempt #2 to hard code vertical line

    focus.append("line")
        .attr({
            "x1": 300,
            "y1": -height,
            "x2": 300,
            "y2": height
        })

    chart.append("rect")
        .attr({"class": "overlay" , "width": width , "height": height})
        .on({
          "mouseover": function() { focus.style("display", null); },
          "mouseout":  function() { focus.style("display", "none"); }, 
          "mousemove": mousemove
        });



function mousemove() {
    var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(sample2, x0, 1),
        d0 = sample2[i-1],
        d1 = sample2[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - margin.right) + "," + yScale(d.close) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text("$" + d.close);

}
```

Comment: `d3.mouse(this)[0]` won't work. Rather you draw a simple vertical line and translate it horizontally as well in your `mousemove` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my comment above, any calculation related to mouse movements must happen in the `mousemove` function.

Here is your fixed example: http://tributary.io/inlet/8677777

I had to move your text out of `focus` so that it could be translated independently.

Comment: How would recommend I clip the lines to ensure that they don't spill over into the axes?  I would like to contain them neatly withing the grid plot? Thanks!